No VSCode auto-completion using .sty file commands
I have created many .sty files that auto-complete in TeXMaker, but recently I switched over to compiling in VSCode. The problem is, even though there's no problem compiling, I have no auto-completion for the commands in the .sty files.
E.G., I have a file called math.sty, where I keep packages like amsfonts, amssymb, etc. and custom commands like
\newcommand{\pderive}[3]{\frac{\partial^{#3}{#1}}{\partial{#2}^{#3}}}

but if I type in my .tex file
\documentclass{letterpaper}{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\RequirePackage{math} % I've also tried \usepackage{} (with .sty) and \input{} (with .tex)

\begin{document}

\pderive

\end{document}

it doesn't expand to
\documentclass{letterpaper}{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\RequirePackage{math} 

\begin{document}

\pderive{}{}{}

\end{document}

Now if I manually put \newcommand{\pderive}[3]{\frac{\partial^{#3}{#1}}{\partial{#2}^{#3}}} into the .tex preamble, it will auto-complete.
Any suggestions?
